# First attempt at designing a 'ProfileActivity'

Tags: android, xml

I designed this layout in Balsamiq for my `ProfileActivity`and I tried to replicate it. The screen on the left fits the correct proportions, whereas the screen on the right has a stretched out view of all the content in the activity.

[image: Balsamiq mockup of my ProfileActivity]

Am I overusing `RelativeLayouts`? Is there a much easier way to make this? How can I make this layout better for a horizontal orientation?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Username"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_location_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/username_text_view"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="User location"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/num_posts_number_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/num_posts_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/num_posts_number_text_view"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/posts_uppercase"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/num_friends_number_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/num_friends_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/num_friends_number_text_view"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/friends_uppercase"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_all_posts_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/view_all_posts" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friends_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/friends"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saved_posts_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/saved_posts"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:linksClickable="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ignored_posts_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/ignored_posts"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/horizontal_rule"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_groups_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/my_groups"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Overusing RelativeLayout

Yes, you're overusing it a bit:

- Many times you wrap a single view inside `RelativeLayout`. Try to remove those wrappers.
- There seem to be an unnecessary layer of `RelativeLayout` around the box with POSTS and FRIENDS.

However, given that your layout is simple, this shouldn't cause performance issues. The only issue I see with this is aesthetic.

### Don't Repeat Yourself

There's a lot of repetition in your text and image elements. It would be good to extract these to styles. For example, create `res/values/styles.xml` like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="box_item">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
    <style name="box_count" parent="box_item">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
    <style name="box_text" parent="box_item">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then in your layout you could simplify some items like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_posts_number_text_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    style="@style/box_count"
    android:text="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_posts_text_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/num_posts_number_text_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    style="@style/box_text"
    android:text="@string/posts_uppercase" />
```

These are just examples, for the text items in your POSTS / FRIENDS boxes. You could apply the same technique everywhere. This will help even more when you have many layout files and want to change something uniformly in all of them.

### Avoid fixed dimensions

You probably already know this, but it's not good practice to use concrete values for width and height. Avoid them as much as possible. For example in your horizontal rule element, setting the width to 300dip seems really unnecessary. It would be better to let it expand to the possible width, minus some padding.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Just a small problem though: in `box_item`, you should get rid of `<item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>` because `box_text` does not have `layout_centerInParent="true"`. Otherwise everything works perfectly. Also, wouldn't it make more sense for the `horizontal_rule` to expand to the max width minus some margin (not padding)?

Comment: Glad you liked it! Thanks for pointing out the problem. I wrote the answer without an IDE at hand, but an equivalent name should exist, you get the idea. As for the horizontal rule, whether you use margin or padding depends mainly on your UI elements and your visual taste. Sometimes the two solutions are equivalent, sometimes they look different. The difference is subtle and hard to explain.